# What's the deal with encapsulatedKey? In Apple's HPKE.Ciphersuite.P521_SHA512_AES_GCM_256 Is this sensitive data?

Tags: public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric, hybrid, apple-cryptokit, shared-secret

Can someone please tell me what this symmetric key is for. I'm thinking the cipher suite will still compute a shared secret because it still needs a public key for decryption from the sender, but I'm bit nervous about sharing a public key and a symmetric key. Can anyone please help me understand what's going on here. It seems like sharing two directives of a symmetric key would only make it less secure and easier to compute. Is it safe to pass this symmetric key back and forth?